# Correct way to implement en/decrypting stream in .NET?

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, file-format

I want to import and export an old game file format, and its data is encrypted. Details are found [here](http://www.bendlins.de/nico/pod/pod2pbdf.txt); shortly summarized, the file is seperated into blocks, each one uses a specific kind of an XOR encryption based on the previous uint, and a checksum trails each block which I'd need to skip when reading data.

Typically, I want to design streams which are laid on the game files to be reusable, and it would be great if there's a stream doing the encryption / decryption in the background, while the developer just works with a `BinaryReader/Writer` to do some `ReadUInt32()` stuff etc.

So I far I researched that there's a `CryptoStream` class in .NET, would the "correct" way to implement en/decryption start with inheriting from that class? I found no articles about someone who tried it that way, thus I'm unsure if I'm completely wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst not C#, [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms384298%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) may provide some insight, showing implementation of the [`ICryptoTransform` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's an example of how that might look in C#, with the XOR-with-previous-block you mention in your use case (no doubt you will have to adjust this to match your exact algorithm):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class XORCryptoTransform : ICryptoTransform
{
    uint previous;
    bool encrypting;

    public XORCryptoTransform(uint iv, bool encrypting)
    {
        previous = iv;
        this.encrypting = encrypting;
    }

    public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i+=4)
        {
            uint block = BitConverter.ToUInt32(inputBuffer, inputOffset + i);
            byte[] transformed = BitConverter.GetBytes(block ^ previous);
            Array.Copy(transformed, 0, outputBuffer, outputOffset + i, Math.Min(transformed.Length, outputBuffer.Length - outputOffset -i));

            if (encrypting)
            {
                previous = block;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = BitConverter.ToUInt32(transformed, 0);
            }
        }

        return inputCount;
    }

    public byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
    {
        var transformed = new byte[inputCount];
        TransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount, transformed, 0);
        return transformed;
    }

    public bool CanReuseTransform
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public int InputBlockSize
    {
        // 4 bytes in uint
        get { return 4; }
    }

    public int OutputBlockSize
    {
        get { return 4; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        uint iv = 0; // first block will not be changed
        byte[] plaintext = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        byte[] ciphertext;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var encryptStream = new CryptoStream(
                memoryStream,
                new XORCryptoTransform(iv, true),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                encryptStream.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length);
            }

            ciphertext = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        byte[] decrypted = new byte[ciphertext.Length];

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ciphertext))
        using (var encryptStream = new CryptoStream(
                memoryStream,
                new XORCryptoTransform(iv, false),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            encryptStream.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
        }

        bool matched = plaintext.SequenceEqual(decrypted);
        Console.WriteLine("Matched: {0}", matched);
    }
}
```

In this example, if the input data is a multiple of the block length (4 bytes for `uint` in your case), there'll be nothing to be done in `TransformFinalBlock`. However, if the data is not a multiple of the block length, the left-over bytes will get handled there.

.NET automatically pads out the array passed to `TransformFinalBlock` with zeroes to bring it up to the block-length, but you can detect that by checking the `inputCount` (which will be the actual input length, not the padded length) and replacing with your own custom (non-zero) padding if your algorithm calls for it.

Comment: Thanks for the example C# code, the summaries in the .NET framework would raise me some questions which the code answers :)

Comment: In the `Array.Copy` line, shouldn't the length be max. `inputCount`? I tried to transform a final block, only 1 byte actually, but he wanted to write 4 bytes into the byte array of length 1.

Comment: From my understanding of your question, you are XOR-ing in blocks of `uint`-length (i.e. 4 bytes), so if you have input that isn't a multiple of 4 bytes in length then you'll need to pad it out to that length.

Comment: True thought. The problem will mostly not arise in practice. I was just testing around with a string of stupid length. My bad!

Comment: It's a good point though, I've updated my example so that it will cope with data that isn't a multiple of the block length. I've also noticed an idiosyncracy of how `TransformFinalBlock` is called from `CryptoStream.Dispose`, so I've moved the `MemoryStream.ToArray` to after the `CryptoStream` has been disposed of when encrypting.

Answer (score 2):

No, inheriting from `CryptoStream` is not the correct thing to do. If you wanted to go that route the correct way to do it is create a class that implements [`ICryptoTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and put the decryption and encryption logic in there. You then pass the `ICryptoTransform` class in as a parameter to the `CryptoStream`.